# PDF from Firebase Storage not displayed in Flutter view

Tags: flutter, pdf

I have this code to display a pdf when user tap on a button. But, it does not work.
I do not see what I am doing wrong here. Please, can you help me to solve this? Many thanks.
I am getting a new view, but the view is blank.
It is working fine when the file is local, I mean on my phone. But when the pdf is on firebase, I am getting a blank page.
I have modified the code.

I have modified the code again. but is still not working. If one of you could help me to solve this it would be appreciated. My project is blocked now. This is driving me nuts.Many thanks.

```
//on another page

Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Display_PDF_Selected_Storage(task_Attachments[j].toString())));
```

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pdfview/flutter_pdfview.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class Display_PDF_Selected_Storage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int pdfIndex;
  final String selectedPdfPath;

  Display_PDF_Selected_Storage(this.selectedPdfPath, {Key key, this.pdfIndex, }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _Display_PDF_Selected_StorageState createState() => _Display_PDF_Selected_StorageState(selectedPdfPath,pdfIndex);
}


class _Display_PDF_Selected_StorageState extends State<Display_PDF_Selected_Storage> {
  PDFViewController controller;

  int indexPage = 0, indexPdf, pages = 0, currentPage = 0;
  bool isReady = false;
  String selectedPdfPath;

  _Display_PDF_Selected_StorageState(this.selectedPdfPath,this.indexPdf,);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final text = '${indexPage + 1} of $pages';

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(selectedPdfPath.split('/').last),
        actions: pages >= 2
        ? [
        Center(child: Text(text)),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left, size: 32),
          onPressed: () {
            final page = indexPage == 0 ? pages : indexPage - 1;
            controller.setPage(page);
          },
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_right, size: 32),
          onPressed: () {
            final page = indexPage == pages - 1 ? 0 : indexPage + 1;
            controller.setPage(page);
          },
        ),
        ]
        : null,
      ),
      body:Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          PDFView(
            filePath: selectedPdfPath,
            autoSpacing: false,
            swipeHorizontal: true,
            enableSwipe: true,
            pageSnap: false,
            pageFling: true,
            onRender: (pages) => setState(() => this.pages = pages),
            onViewCreated: (controller) =>
                setState(() => this.controller = controller),
            onPageChanged: (indexPage, _) =>
                setState(() => this.indexPage = indexPage),
            //  errorMessage.isEmpty
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future <String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async{
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/guidelines.pdf');
  }

  Future<File> writeToLocal(Uint8List bytes) async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    return file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try this widget:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pilot_dispatch_app/tools/fs_utils.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart';

class PdfFromUrl extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;

  const PdfFromUrl({Key? key, required this.url}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PdfFromUrlState createState() => _PdfFromUrlState();
}

class _PdfFromUrlState extends State<PdfFromUrl> {
  //String pathPDF = "";
  String remotePDFpath = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PDFScreen(path: widget.url);
  }
}

class PDFScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? path;

  PDFScreen({Key? key, this.path}) : super(key: key);

  _PDFScreenState createState() => _PDFScreenState();
}

class _PDFScreenState extends State<PDFScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  // final Completer<PDFViewController> _controller =
  //     Completer<PDFViewController>();
  int? pages = 0;
  int? currentPage = 0;
  bool isReady = false;
  String errorMessage = '';
  String? getFileName(String? pdfUrl) {
    if (pdfUrl != null) {
      var result = pdfUrl.substring(pdfUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      if (result.contains('?')) {
        result = result.substring(0, result.lastIndexOf('?'));
      }
      return result;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var title = getFileName(widget.path);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        title: Text(title!),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.share),
            onPressed: () async {
              try {
                final pdfUint8List = await FsUtils.getUint8ListFromUrl(
                  widget.path!,
                );
                if (pdfUint8List != null) {
                  final file = await writeToLocal(pdfUint8List);
                  Share.shareFiles([file.path]);
                }
              } catch (e) {
                Logger().e(
                  e.toString(),
                );
              }
              //Share.share(widget.path!);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SfPdfViewer.network(
          widget.path!,
          //'https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf',
          enableDocumentLinkAnnotation: false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  return directory.path;
}

Future<File> get _localFile async {
  final path = await _localPath;
  return File('$path/guidelines.pdf');
}

Future<File> writeToLocal(Uint8List bytes) async {
  final file = await _localFile;
  // Write the file
  return file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried but not been able to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this,

1. Get the download URL of the object stored in Firebase storage:

```dart
final docUrl = await FirebaseStorage.instance
  .ref()
  .child("path/to/file.pdf")
  .getDownloadURL();
```

2. Download the file from URL using [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager):

```dart
final docFile = DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(docUrl);
```

3. Load the PDF from file path using [flutter_pdfview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview):

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext) {
  return PDFView(
    filePath: docFile.path,
  );
}
```